# Ubuntu 18.10 don't recognize a formatted SDD

Tags: partitioning

Ok, I have a problem with Ubuntu 18.10 not recognizing my SSD. I bought a laptop that had OEM partitions and Windows on it. The Windows had problems so I tried Recovery but it failed after that I couldn't boot OR install Ubuntu. I used the Repair-Disk of Linux to fix the MBR (supposedly)and the installation of Ubuntu recognized the SSD. I formatted all partitions except from EFI. I tried to install on the SSD but the installation of Ubuntu got stuck. After that Linux never recognized the SSD again. I have installed Ubuntu 18.10 on my secondary drive and here's what fdisk prints:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 2,3 MiB, 2355200 bytes, 4600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 140,9 MiB, 147722240 bytes, 288520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 87,9 MiB, 92123136 bytes, 179928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 3,7 MiB, 3878912 bytes, 7576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 14,5 MiB, 15208448 bytes, 29704 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 140,7 MiB, 147496960 bytes, 288080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 87,9 MiB, 92114944 bytes, 179912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: BA1E2DC1-25A0-45EF-9FD4-2E32E8D5C47A

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 1953523711 1952473088  931G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/loop8: 34,2 MiB, 35827712 bytes, 69976 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 13 MiB, 13619200 bytes, 26600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 42,1 MiB, 44183552 bytes, 86296 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 2,3 MiB, 2355200 bytes, 4600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

This is what gparted shows:
[image]

Any ideas what I could do?

EDIT: Look answer below to see what the problem was. Probably should work on many laptops.

Comment: fdisk may not be the best tool. And first of all check whether or not the drive is still recognized in UEFI. (And you have a UEFI system with GPT drives, you don't have and shouldn't have MBRs anywhere).

Comment: Ok I'm a complete noob here as you can understand. By UEFI you mean check the BIOS like thing right, so I know that the computer actually recognizes the SSD?

Comment: Yes, I prefer using the correct terminology - UEFI replaces BIOS but many people and vendors, unfortunately insist in the old name that is no longer applicable -.

Comment: Yeah, I completely agree with you. You're doing it right. Give a moment and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Ok I have an M.2 PCIe SSD with a code on my system. The primary hard drive is the HDD tho.

Comment: You can use GParted (may need to be installed) or the already included Disks tool to get a visual representation of the partitions. Hopefully it'll show what's happening with the M.2 drive. You may [edit] and include screenshots in the question.

Comment: OK, I uploaded the picture :D. It just shows the HDD

Comment: In the upper right corner it has a dropdown menu. Are you sure there's no other drive?

Comment: Yes I checked this and the Devices tab also. :(

Comment: Weird... It could be due to an unsupported (by Linux distros) SATA mode  - RAID - but usually that setting is global and would prevent the other drive to be recognized also. So, I hope I'm wrong, but it is possible the M.2 drive is now defective. That it was at some point recognized but now isn't is suspicious.

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty certain it's in RAID mode, can I change that somehow so maybe it can be recognised by Linux?

Comment: Yes, try changing to AHCI. If it's now recognized you'll also be able to install Ubuntu normally as originally intended.

Comment: I'm on a laptop, this doesn't have to do with anything right?

Comment: SATA modes are just different ways the controller handles the drives. IDE or "native IDE" is for compatibility with (very) old OSes and shouldn't be used. AHCI and "RAID" is more or less the same but the latter enables features not always useful. Generally AHCI should be used (and the "RAID" mode - not a real RAID though - in laptops is only supported in Windows).

Comment: Ok, changed it to AHCI and now everything works! Thank you so much for everything! :D

Comment: I'll post it as an answer. You can latter upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: @DaveKimble - Interesting for you. See answer of Gabriela Garcia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After troubleshooting it was concluded that the SATA mode in UEFI settings was set to "RAID" mode which isn't supported by Ubuntu and other Linux distros.

That was the reason why the drive wasn't being recognized by Ubuntu.

Solution:

- Change SATA mode to **AHCI**.

Comment: This solution also worked for me in a similar situation.

Comment: Also successfully managed to install Ubuntu on SSD. SO much faster than Windows btw. Awesome help! Thank you very much! :D

Comment: If this answer solved the issue for you, kindly mark it as the best answer so that others can see how the issue was resolved.

Comment: How do I do that? ^_^